# uialertview and delegate (delayed in code)

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, ipad

I'm checking if file already exists and if it is, I'm alerting the user if he wants o replace the file. I'm using alert view and a delegate.
However when i run it using the simulator by the time the user selects YES or NO the program already run pass it and the blnVal has NO value regardless 
I'm not sure what i'm missing here.?
 (I searched the database here but couldn't find any related specific question)

```
  -(void) chkFile2Save
    {
        short tst;

        NSString* documentsPath = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0];

        NSString* foofile = [documentsPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:pln2Save.text];
        BOOL fileExists = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:foofile];



        if(fileExists)
        {
            blnVal=NO;
           [self AskFileSave];
        }

        //blnVal always NO for whatever reason ... ?
        if(blnVal==NO)
            tst=5;
              //...
        else {
            tst=10;
            //..
        }


    }



    - (void) AskFileSave
    {
        UIAlertView *alertFileSave = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"" message:@"File already exists.  Override the file with current data?" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"No" otherButtonTitles:@"Yes", nil];

        [alertFileSave setTag:10];
        [alertFileSave show];
        [alertFileSave release];
    }

    -(void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
    {


        //override file exists
        if([alertView tag]==10)
        {
            if(buttonIndex == 1)
            {
                blnVal=YES;
            }
            else
            {
                blnVal=NO;
            }

        }
    }
```

Comment: Where is blnVal stored/defined? And you should put in some NSLogs to see what the flow through your code is in the delegate method when you press Yes and No.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are calling

```
[self AskFileSave];
```

that will execute

```
- (void) AskFileSave
```

than the execution will go back to :

```
//blnVal always NO for whatever reason ... ?
        if(blnVal==NO)
            tst=5;
              //...
        else {
            tst=10;
            //..
        }
```

You should move that part of the code to delegate method, There you have the option what the user selected, because the UIAlerView will not stop the code execution.

```
-(void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
{
    //override file exists
    if([alertView tag]==10)
    {
        if(buttonIndex == 1)
        {
            blnVal=YES;
            tst = 10;
        }
        else
        {
            blnVal=NO;
            tst=5;
        }

    }
}
```

I hope it helps!

Comment: yes, the execution is not stopped. I have other things to check before i execute (beyond the code above). But i guess there is no other way around it. Thanks!

Comment: No there isn't a safe way, just unsafe. This is the simplest, cleaner solution what I know: move a part of the logic after the [self AskFileSave]; to the UIAlertView's Delegate method.